# Como converter timestamp do banco de dados para preencher um campo datetime-local?

Tags: laravel-5, conversão, timestamp, datetime-local

Preciso preencher um campo:

```
<input id="date" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" value="{{$task->date}}" name="date">
```

O retorno vem em formato *timestamp* (*"2016-09-20 10:00:00"*), existe algum *helper* do *laravel* que converta o formato?

Comment: Não costumo usar muito, mas sei que o Laravel é meio que integrado com o [carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) que nas poucas vezes que precisei facilitou muito.

Comment: @NeuberOliveira sim o carbon ajuda muito, mas nesse momento preciso apenas converter o formato para que preencha um campo datetime-local :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Galera consegui, usei dessa forma:

```
<input id="date" type="datetime-local" class="form-control"
                                   value="{{date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s", strtotime($task->date))}}"
                                   name="date" placeholder="Data">
```

Comment: Bom ter achado a solução e compartilhar +1. Um dica que eu dou é você criar um helper próprio carregar no seu `Laravel` e diminuir esse imenso código na View. Parabéns ...

Comment: @VirgilioNovic obrigado pela dica, vou tentar aplicar ^^

Answer (score 1):

I input do tipo `date` do HTML5 só aceita um tipo de formatação, que é `AAAA/mm/dd` ou seja `2016-09-19`, sabendo disso você pode fazer da seguinte maneira.

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" value="{{ date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($task->date)) }}">
```

Comment: É do tipo datetime-local ou seja Y/m/d H:i:s, mas mesmo usando date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($task->date))  não funcionou :/

Comment: utilize o mesmo principio, alterei novamente.

Comment: Deu na mesma amigo, já havia tentado isso :/

Answer (score 1):

Só para ilustrar acho que seria algo do tipo:

```
<input id="date" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" value="{{Carbon::createFromFormat('Y/m/d H:i:s', $task->date)->toDateTimeString()}}" name="date">
```

Comment: Não sei se é possível utilizar o carbon na view, mas de qualquer forma obrigado a tentativa, usei dessa forma e funcionou value="{{date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s", strtotime($task->date))}}"